# sql server group by clause error

Tags: sql-server

I keep getting the aggregate group by clause error on the below query. I'm new to SQL and can't quite figure it out. I keep getting duplicate records due to the `JDEppsin` table and a distinct clause won't do it either.

```
SELECT 
      JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.WorkOrderNumber,
      JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.Quantity,
      JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.LineNumber,  
      JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.SKU,
      JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.SKUDesc1,
      JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.SKUDesc2,
      arc_JDEPPSIn.PalletSheet,
      arc_JDEPPSIn.PalletConfigDesc,
      arc_JDEPPSIn.LabelAlcVol,
      arc_JDEPPSIn.CartonInkjetCode,
      arc_JDEPPSIn.SpecialInstructions,
      JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.WAWR02
      FROM [WBPC_MES_Integration].[dbo].[arc_JDEPPSIn]
join [WBPC_MES_Integration].[dbo].[JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport] on arc_JDEPPSIn.WorkOrderNumber = JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.WorkOrderNumber
where JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.startdate between getdate()-7 and getdate()+5
group by arc_JDEPPSIn.workordernumber
```

I googled about using a virtual table to group it this is what I've come up with but I just dont know how to join I'm self taught so trying to figure it out

Comment: Column list is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Please provide sample output of current query.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is. Every column in the SELECT that is not an aggregate function (SUM(), AVG(), etc) must be in the GROUP BY clause. You've got 12 columns that are not an aggregate function, and not a single aggregate function in the SELECT. You need to find a book or online tutorial on basic SQL.

Comment: i keep getting duplicates but using a distinct clause doenst fix this in the JDE workorderin table there is a date time field with different dates which i think is causing the problems

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use a GROUP clause all non-aggregate values (not SUM, COUNT, AVG etc...) in your SELECT statement need to appear in your group by statement. Try adding:

```
GROUP BY
JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.WorkOrderNumber,
JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.Quantity,
JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.LineNumber,  
JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.SKU,
JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.SKUDesc1,
JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.SKUDesc2,
arc_JDEPPSIn.PalletSheet,
arc_JDEPPSIn.PalletConfigDesc,
arc_JDEPPSIn.LabelAlcVol,
arc_JDEPPSIn.CartonInkjetCode,
arc_JDEPPSIn.SpecialInstructions,
JDEWorkOrderIn_LastImport.WAWR02
```

With that said, if you do not have an aggregate value you shouldn't need to group. I would use SELECT DISTINCT instead if you are trying to remove duplicates. If you are not, then just remove the group by.

Comment: i can use distinct as it errors with The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Comment: Apologies, I did not realize you were using the text data type. If possible I would replace it with varchar(max) as the text data type has been deprecated, but having one column in my database that is text data type and the inability to change it, I understand how difficult this can be.